# Making a navigation drawer with an ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm working on an application which I would like to add a navigation drawer to that contains a header (image, fullname and email) and an ExpandableListView where the user navigates around the app.

So far, I've created the ExpandableListView with the navigation system, but I didn't manage to make the header for the navigation drawer.

I've tried to make an `<include/>` tag to implement the header in the drawer_layout.xml, but to no avail.

This is how I want it to look (ignore the ExpandableListView entries; just an example): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkmbr.jpg

Here are my layout files:

**drawer_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Activity Content-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer Items -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="#444444"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#444444">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Example Example"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="example@gmail.com"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circleView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circleView" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm also using a custom ExpandableListAdapter (will post the code if needed).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can wrap the `ExpandableListView` within a `LinearLayout` and add other layouts to that `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap your `ExpandableListView` within any other view.

The reason for that is `DrawerLayout` can have two child view, one for `NavigationDrawer` and other which acts as the `Container View`, i am posting yours xml file with additions see if it helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!-- Activity Content-->
     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">
     </FrameLayout>

     <!-- Navigation Drawer Items -->
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="240dp">

         <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="#444444"/>

      </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I put everything in a LinearLayout, what parameter do I pass to boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList); ? Currently it takes in the ExpandableListView.

Comment: give `id` to that `LinearLayout` and then in java pass that `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. You saved me a ton of hours. Cheers.